# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/model/doc/DocumentationProvider

Tags: spring, cxf, swagger

I am trying to integrate swagger. I am following steps as given [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/Swagger2Feature). application context and pom.xml is configured same.
when restarting tomcat getting this error.

```
2018-04-30 14:01:33 ERROR ContextLoader:351 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productAPIServer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/model/doc/DocumentationProvider
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
```

I have included

```
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
 <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger</artifactId>
 <version>3.1.7</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
 <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description</artifactId>
 <version>3.1.7</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
 <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
 <version>3.1.7</version>
 </dependency>
```

Changes in context xml file:

```
<bean id="jacksonJsonProviderFasterxml" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider" />
<bean id="swagger2Feature"   class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.swagger.Swagger2Feature">

<property name="basePath" value="/staticdata-web-service"/>
<property name="license" value=""/>
<property name="licenseUrl" value=""/>
<property name="title" value="Static data web service"/>
</bean>
```

Added feature

```
<jaxrs:features>
<ref bean="swagger2Feature" />
</jaxrs:features>
```

Comment: I have also tried with     <!-- JAXRS providers -->
    <bean id="jsonProvider" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider" />

Answer (score 1):

You have a version mismatch. When you search on [Maven](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cc%3A%22DocumentationProvider%22) for that class, you'll find that the package of the `DocumentationProvider` has changed  from version 3.0.x to 3.1.x

> org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/model/doc/DocumentationProvider

to

> org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/model/wadl/DocumentationProvider

It's hard to tell where the mismatch is located without having insight into your entire build and package dependencies. But you may want to run

```
 mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

in your project folder to see which package versions come into question for raising your `ClassNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

use below dependency in your maven project to solve your issue,

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-rs-json-basic -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-json-basic</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: it would be good to add some context how it solves the problem